# $.data is undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

Following is the markup of my MVC razor view:

```
<div style="visibility:visible;">
var data = [
        {"id":"1", "ui_bgcolor":"Green", "ui_forecolor": "Black"},
        {"id":"2", "ui_bgcolor":"Amber", "ui_forecolor": "Black"},
        {"id":"3", "ui_bgcolor":"Red", "ui_forecolor": "White"}
]
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetGradeDLLItemStyling() {
        $.each(data, function (i) {
            alert(data[i].UIBackgroundColor);
        });
    }
</script>
```

I am receiving $.data is undefined error in script block. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data isn't defined in a script block, hence isn't available.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = [
        {"id":"1", "ui_bgcolor":"Green", "ui_forecolor": "Black"},
        {"id":"2", "ui_bgcolor":"Amber", "ui_forecolor": "Black"},
        {"id":"3", "ui_bgcolor":"Red", "ui_forecolor": "White"}
]
</script>
```

Comment: I am building this data array inside razor code by iterating through a collection contained within model's property

Comment: this was a generated HTML markup... I corrected my razor code to build the data collection inside script tag.. and its working now.. thanks Man, you gave me that idea

Comment: @Nirman glad i could help. So i guess you should accept the answer as the correct one :)

Comment: yes... ofcourse.. but it still says it will allow me to accept answer only after next 4 mins :)